# Cбитый с толку / сбитый с толка

Tags: орфография, падежи

Как правильно: «сбитый с толку» или «сбитый с толка». И почему?

На удивление статистика упоминаний по точному совпадению (Гугл) показывает, что «сбитый с толку» встечается гораздо чаще, чем «сбитый с толка»: 439000 результатов против 3690.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как правильно: «сбитый с толку» или «сбитый с толка»

В качестве устоявшегося выражения употребляют только ***"[сбитый] с толку"***.

Но вопрос-то интересный на самом деле. Проблема в том, что такое "правильно". Грамматически "правилен" скорее вариант *"с толка"* - это обычный родительный падеж.
Вариант же "с толку", а также "без толку", "мало толку" и подобные можно рассматривать скорее как второй родительный падеж (партитив); сравните: "с мёду" - в значении "поев меда"), "с холоду [пришел], "с пылу, с жару".
Однако в современном языке партитив свободно используется только для обозначении части или небольшого количества чего-то (выпить чаю, набрать песку), раньше же он мог использовался более широко, в том числе и для выражения проявления чего-то, не имеющего количественного выражения. Это и нашло выражение в ряде закрепившихся оборотов, в том числе и рассматриваемом (часто с предлогом с): *навести шороху, задать треску, с пылу с жару, сбить с толку*.

Answer (score 2):

По словарю.

[Русское словесное ударение](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA&all=x)

> **толк,** *-а* и *-у*; б**е**з толку (безрезультатно); сбить с т**о**лку

См. также: [панталык: сбить(ся) с панталыку](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BA)